# LUCENE Version conflict between Elasticsearch and project dependency

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

Project I am working on requires the use of both Elasticsearch and a dependency (I didn't design or get to dictate its design) that utilizes Lucene and running into a version conflict between the two.  The following error is spit out when I try to start the project

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_5_2_1
    at org.elasticsearch.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:39)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.<init>(StreamOutput.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.BytesStreamOutput.<init>(BytesStreamOutput.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.BytesStreamOutput.<init>(BytesStreamOutput.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.BytesStreamOutput.<init>(BytesStreamOutput.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.builder(XContentBuilder.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.arrayToParsableString(Setting.java:726)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.lambda$listSetting$26(Setting.java:672)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting$2.getRaw(Setting.java:676)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.lambda$listSetting$24(Setting.java:660)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.listSetting(Setting.java:665)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.listSetting(Setting.java:660)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.<clinit>(NetworkService.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.newPluginService(TransportClient.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:119)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:247)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:92)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:71)
```

Any idea on whether or not its possible to resolve without being able to dictate the design of the dependency or Elasticsearch?

Comment: Feel dumb, was able to solve it by bringing in the Lucene core dependency at the version needed (5.2.1).

Comment: Don't feel bad; it happens. You can make amends by writing an answer to you own question that documents exactly what it took to fix the problem. That way, if someone has a similar problem they will be able to learn from the answer.

Comment: Yep I am going to, was waiting to see if any other posts come first with other solutions I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up adding the Lucene core dependency version that is being mentioned in the error to the project.  `build.gradle` now contains `compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-core', version: '5.2.1'` and that solved the problem.